# python code using 1 module in python 3.10 and 1 module in python 3.8

Tags: python, version

I'm looking for how to use 2 modules working with differents python version.

Example :

```
import os
import sys
import time
import signal
# application specific imports
import epics                     #  working under python 3.10
import simply_py as simply       #  working under python 3.8
from simply_py import Message
```

Many Thanks

Comment: this is dupe question probably, you will solve with try-except on imports

Comment: Get the version via `sys` (for example `py_version = f"{sys.version_info.major}.{sys.version_info.minor}"`) and make the resp. code parts conditional on the result?